# How to optimize imported photos from digital camera?

Tags: macos, photos, camera, photos.app

I'm importing photos from my camera using Photos application, but how can I optimize these photos.

My camera does 5.5MB big JPEG images but I want somehow lower the resolution and also the quality does not need to be 100%.

Can I somehow set the imported photo quality in Photos application or can I somewhere found the imported photos and lower the quality using some other application?

Comment: If you don't need 5.5MB big photos, why don't you try to change the settings of your camera?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend importing your photos at full resolution, on the off chance that you ever want to crop or make a big print or display on a high res screen in the future. With Apple Photos, you can import at full resolution and it will upload the full image to iCloud.

Then, under Preferences: iCloud Photo Library select Optimize Mac Storage. Photos will now automatically switch to thumbnails when you start running low on space, and will automatically download the full-res version whenever you need to edit, view or export an image.

Answer (score 1):

Usually cameras provide settings that will allow you to shoot photos of smaller resolution, so if I wouldn't want images of that resolution, I would first look to change the shooting settings.

However when I want to batch resize images in mac, here is some of my techniques:

**With an Automator Workflow**
 I have created an automator workflow of the following 2 steps:

1. Ask for Finder Items: with Allow Multiple Selection.
2. Scale Images: where I specify the desired dimension.

Then I click to run it, it asks me for the Finder Items, I select the images I want to resize and voila.

Note that the above 2 automator steps are destructive, meaning that your images cannot be reverted back to their original size. It's generally recommended to add an extra step in your workflow to copy the files before resizing them.

**Using Photos Export**
Another option using Photos, is to use the export feature and create your desired export settings to rescale your images. Then you can import them back.

**Image Optimization**
Finally there is another tool I use it when I want to optimize jpeg files for the web: It is the **[imageOptim](https://imageoptim.com)**. It won't resize the images, rather than it will try to compress them even more, in order to save in weight.